# Swift HMAC doesn't match NodeJS HMAC, but only sometimes!

Tags: hash, ios, hmac, node.js

I have discovered a HUGE issue in my code, and I have literally no idea what is causing this.

SO, when I send requests to my server I hash a string thats in the request. This is sometimes user input.

My app is multi language so I have to support all "ä" chars etc.

So with the normal english letters/chars numbers etc, this hashing method works like a dream. BUT when the string being hashed and compared contains a "ä" or a "ö" (Not specifically those, it literally might be that any char not in the Base64 set will cause this) the hash doesn't match!

This is an absolute and complete disaster, and I have not noticed it this far. I have tried basically everything I know to try to fix this, and googling, and I am out of luck so far.

I generate the hash in Swift inputting the string and secretToken into this function and saving the output as a HTTP header:

```
func hmac(string: String, key: String) -> String {

    var digest = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))

    CCHmac(CCHmacAlgorithm(kCCHmacAlgSHA256), key, key.count, string, string.count, &digest)

    let data = Data(digest)

    return data.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined()

}
```

How I compare the hash in NodeJS:

```
if (hashInTheRequest === crypto.createHmac('sha256', secretToken).update(stringToHash).digest('hex')) {
    //Good to go
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the characters by any chance encoded twice or maybe URL encoded? `%FC` instead of `ü`, maybe?

Comment: @BernhardDöbler I am sending the string in a JSON value in the http data. So that should be impossible.

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to a composition issue. You mentioned non-latin characters, but didn't specify any concrete examples, where you had problems.

## What is composition?

Unicode aims to be able to represent any character used by humanity. However, many characters are similar, such as `u`, `ü`, `û` and `ū`. The original idea was to just assign a code point to every possible combination. As one might imagine, this is not the most effective way to store things. Instead, the "base" character is used, and then a combining character is added to it.

Let's look at an example: `ü`

`ü` can be represented as `U+00FC`, also known as `LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS`.

`ü` can also be represented as `U+0075` (`u`), followed by `U+0308` (`◌̈`), also known as `LATIN SMALL LETTER U`, followed by `COMBINING DIARESIS`.

## Why is this problematic?

Because hash functions don't know what a string is. All they care about is bytes. As such, a string has to be decoded to a string of bytes. As was shown above, there are multiple different ways to decode a string, which means that two different systems can decode the same logical string to different bytes, thus resulting in different hashes.

## How can I fix this?

You have to explicitly define how the string will be decoded on both platforms, to ensure that both decode the strings in the exact same manner.